# node-postgres throwing connection error when chaining 2 queries together via promises and then trying to end the connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise

I'm getting strange behaviour in node-postgres when inserting data into tables. When running this block of code, it works perfectly:

```
    client
      .query(
        format(
          "INSERT INTO precipitation(xref, yref, calendarmonth, val) VALUES %L",
          dataToWrite
        )
      )
      .then(() => {
        client.end();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        client.end();
      });
```

Note that I'm using pg-format to format an array of arrays (dataToWrite) in order to insert each array as a row into the table with a single statement. There's about 60,000 rows of data being created.

I want to chain another query before this, to insert data to another table on the same db. However, this code throws an error:

```
client
  .query(
    "INSERT INTO meta_data(header, units, vers, coords, refs) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)",
    metaRows
  )
  .then(() => {
    client.query(
      format(
        "INSERT INTO precipitation(xref, yref, calendarmonth, val) VALUES %L",
        dataToWrite
      )
    );
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("test")
    client.end();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    client.end();
  });
```

The first statement executes correctly, and metaRows is inserted into meta_data without issue. But now the statement that was working in the first code block above is throwing an error and the dataToWrite variable's arrays aren't being inserted into the table. This is the error in the terminal:

```
(node:20116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/george/NorthCoders/Job_Applications/jba-data-challenge/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:36)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/george/NorthCoders/Job_Applications/jba-data-challenge/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:58:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:20116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20116) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The error hints that closing the connection via client.end() is causing the issue - I have tried removing this and the data does seem to be inserted when running the code again, although I have to manually close the connection in the terminal or open a new shell to check this. But I am confused as to why the client.end() would be an issue, as it isn't when executing the query in the first code block, and as far as I know using promises should wait for the statement to complete before running the next then() block. However, it looks like the then() block closing the connection runs before the statement has finished executing, as the "test" console log in the second code block is being logged before the error is thrown.

I also do have a catch() block to handle errors in the promise chain, so I'm not sure what the error is referring to there.

Any advice on what's happening and how to get around this would be appreciated. I'd like to keep using promises if possible. I can attach the SQL code if helpful, but there's not much to see and I don't think it's the cause of the issue.

Comment: You need to return the value so that its passed to the next then. https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Can I porpose using async...await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await to make your code more readable.

Comment: @kg99 Thanks for the response - adding a return before the second client.query() resolved the issue as you said. I hadn't realised that this would need returning, I thought returning was only required when you needed to explicitly use the return value in the next then block. Clearly I need to brush up on my promises. Thanks again.

Comment: And yes, I still need to learn how to refactor with async/await, I see it more and more often used over vanilla promises. I know it's not hard, but one thing at a time...

Comment: Actually I've now refactored it using async/await and it looks much better. Thanks again.